# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized, connection's current state is closed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

In the first place I would be thankful for all of you. I am trying to upload my website to a host that was working great when I was on *localhost*, but now, after I uploaded it, I am getting this error:

> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized, ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

I tried to use SQL Server web host access for *localhost* and it worked, 
I'm using Class call DB which have connections string.

```
SqlConnection cn;
SqlCommand cmd;
DataTable dt;

public SqlDataAdapter sda;
public SqlDataReader sdr;

private void BeRedy(CommandType CT, string DBCall)
{
    try
    {
        cn = new SqlConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BooksConnectionString"].ToString();
        cn.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand(DBCall);
        cmd.CommandType = CT;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand();
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Connection = cn;
    }
}

public SqlDataReader ReadQuery(string query)
{
    BeRedy(CommandType.Text, query);

    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        cn = new SqlConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BooksConnectionString"].ToString();
        cn.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        return dr;
    }
    else
    {
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        return dr;
    }
}

public void BindDataList(string query, DataList DTS)
{
    String SqlSelect = query;
    DataTable dt = ReadQueryDt(SqlSelect);
    DTS.DataSource = dt;
    DTS.DataBind();
}   

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadMostWatchedVideo();
}    

void LoadMostWatchedVideo()
{
    string query = "SELECT TOP (4) * FROM Video ORDER BY watched DESC";
    DataTable dt = db.ReadQueryDt(query);
    DtTopWatched.DataSource = dt;
    DtTopWatched.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: So when the connection does not open the first try you just ignore the problem?    You just swallow (ignore) the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code has some severe issues. Have you sat down and actually thought about it? You need to think through what you're trying to accomplish.

First off, do not store a SqlCommand or SqlConnection as a field in a class. They should generally only be local variables, and they should be closed as quickly as possible.

Another tip is to not use a DataTable. They're much more difficult to work with than defining an actual class to represent your data.

When working with classes instead of DataTable, it's nice to have a library that can convert from the results of a SQL query into a strongly typed class automatically. We call these libraries "Object Relational Mappers". Stack Overflow itself uses [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper). It's simple and fast. You can install it to your project via NuGet.

Here's one way to improve this code. Notice how I don't check conditions that can't happen.

```
// This class will represent a video.
// The names of the properties should match the names of your columns in your database.
// Since I don't know the actual names of your columns, I'm taking a guess.
public class Video
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}

// Your actual data access should happen in this class.
// This keeps your UI code separated from your database logic
public class SqlServerVideoRepository
{
    readonly string _connectionString;

    public VideoRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionstring = connectionString;
    }

    public List<Video> LoadMostWatchedVideos()
    {
        using(var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            //Query is an extension method in the Dapper namespace
            return connection.Query<Video>("SELECT TOP (4) * FROM Video ORDER BY watched DESC").AsList();
        }
    }
}


//now in your code behind
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        var videoRepository = new SqlServerVideoRepository(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BooksConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        var videos = videoRepository.LoadMostWatchedVideos();
        DtTopWatched.DataSource = videos;
        DtTopWatched.DataBind();
    }       
}
```

Comment: thx a lot bro  for your support its working and nice code it just was need some edit its working i tried it in one of the pages and im going to change other codes